# phpMyAdmin 404 error after upgrade to PHP 5.5

Tags: php5, upgrade

Ubuntu 12.04, just upgraded from PHP 5.3 to 5.5.9
Before I could access phpmyadmin from any of the servers by just adding "/phpmyadmin" after the ip address. Websites are working.

Eg.

```
64.236.99.123/phpmyadmin
64.236.99.124/phpmyadmin
```

Now I'm getting a 404 error. phpMyAdmin's configurations look to be untouched, and its "apache.conf" is linked to apache's `conf.d`.

So I don't see why it's not working as before. Any ideas?

Comment: What do your apache access and error logs say?

Comment: Access log shows:
`69.123.156.189 - buttleb [11/Mar/2014:20:30:09 -0700] "GET /phpmyadmin HTTP/1.1"
404 501 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like
 Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.146 Safari/537.36"` Error log shows nothing.

Comment: why are we voting to close? It seems like a server configuration question to me, and the solution will end up being value to many people who have not upgraded to Apache 2.4 yet, I think.

Answer (score 3):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19176094/631764

The answer is that Apache 2.4 uses the folder `conf-available` instead of `conf.d` as in Apache 2.4

The linked-to answer says to `cp` the file over and then activate it. But usually you have a symbolic link to phpmyadmin.conf rather than a copy. It's better to only have a single file you need to make changes to. The regular file you link to is in `/etc/phpmyadmin/`

So here is what I did, and it worked.

```
sudo cp -av /etc/apache2/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/
sudo a2enconf phpmyadmin
sudo service apache2 restart
```

That way you still have a symbolic link to the original file and you only have to make changes in one place (`/etc/phpmyadmin/`) instead of in multiple places. `a2enconf` creates a symbolic link in `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/`. You have to restart apache to see the effects of the change